# Table design for jQuery-query-builder output

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, relational-database, query-builder

Given this object, anyone can suggest what can be a good design for tables to save this in a relational database specifically in Ms Sql Server?
And also a way to save it to that table then retrieve it just like this object.
It is generated from [jQuery-query-builder](http://querybuilder.js.org/).

```
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "condition": "OR",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "category",
          "field": "category",
          "type": "integer",
          "input": "select",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "2"
        },
        {
          "id": "category",
          "field": "category",
          "type": "integer",
          "input": "select",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "condition": "OR",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "price",
          "field": "price",
          "type": "double",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "greater_or_equal",
          "value": "4000"
        },
        {
          "id": "price",
          "field": "price",
          "type": "double",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "less_or_equal",
          "value": "5000"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "name",
      "field": "name",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "Sample1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You have a good point, I will move it if there's no answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Me Code Review requires an already working solution, otherwise it is off-topic. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777) to understand what should belong on Code Review.

Comment: That said, I don't think that this is a good question for Stack Overflow either, as it is basically asking for someone to do the work for you, rather than to seek understanding.

Comment: Hi @200_success, I'm not seeking for direct answer, maybe indirect answer will do. And as far as I know and read most of the question here in Stack Overflow has someone answer and do the work for the solution.

Comment: Yes, but it is expected that you show us what you have already tried, and then ask for help on a specific issue. This looks like you've hardly started.

Comment: That's all I've got, can you help with the design?

Comment: Thanks for the info @200_success. I'll have to remember that limitation of the code review stack exchange. I also know there is a programmers stack exchange, but I don't know much about it, but it seems to have questions that are somewhat similar to this one, but I don't see it likely that this question will be receiving an answer here on Stack Overflow. I would help out if I knew more about databases, but I don't :(.